# ad-hoc $ ansible -u root Permission denied

Tags: ansible

- Default ansible 2.9 configuration.
- User `user` exists both on the control and the hosts.
- Control and hosts have each other's ssh public keys for both users.

From the control host:

`root$ ansible all -a "echo whatever"` works

`user$ ansible all -a "echo whatever"` works

`user$ ansible all -a "echo whatever" -u root` doesn't work.

Error: `... Failed to connect to the host via ssh: root@xhost: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password) ...`

I tried using `--become*` with no success.  How to make that work? what am I missing?

Comment: `root$ ansible all -a "echo whatever" -u user` also works

Comment: `user` has `user ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` sudo configuration

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have root credentials of all remote hosts. You can copy them to your host using `ssh-copy-id` for example.

Comment: The question reads "Control and hosts have each other's ssh public keys for both users."

Answer (score 0):

`user$ sudo ansible all -a "echo whatever" -u root`